# JAVA - Can't add to HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, addition

I am very new to JAVA and I wrote this code:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
map.add("Key",13);
```

Why is it giving the error on eclipse:

```
The method add(String, int) is undefined for the type Map<String,Integer>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `add` method. The method you want is `put`.

```
map.put("Key", 13);
```

See the Javadocs here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K, V)

Comment: No problem, @JohnBlack . If you're done here with this problem you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark under my score, or you can ask more questions either in the comments here or by editting your post.

Comment: Yes the annoying thing is when I click in accept, it tells to me wait 10 minutes.

Comment: No worries in that case.